# Каким хуком вывести все товары из корзины WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как вывести хуком все товары из корзины WooCommerce?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576667/get-cart-item-name-quantity-all-details-woocommerce

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576667/get-cart-item-name-quantity-all-details-woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

```
global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
            echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
        }
```

Comment: Скопировали ответ из ссылки в моем комменте?)))

Comment: Ну вы же  это не сделали) не все понимают английский. А вам спасибо. Действительно помогло!

Comment: А зачем дублировать, если уже такой вопрос был? Тут достаточно комментария со ссылкой

Comment: Как зачем, что бы русские пользователи пользовались.

Comment: Для этого есть ассоциации, я создал во втором комментарии